# Kafka connection to node -1 failed due to authentication

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, messagebroker

I am using kafka version 2.12-2.2.1 in windows operating system. I have implemented tls on my local windows systems using the process of signed certificates.
The kafka is running fine and there is one command to check if certificates are installed on kafka.

```
openssl s_client -debug -connect localhost:9093 -tls1
```

But when I try to connect to `localhost:9093` and using producer or consumer it is throwing me an error saying :

> connection to node -1 failed due to authentication

I have tried everything, I am stuck even the documentation provided is not giving any hints to solve this error.

**Note:** One more addition how can I see the list of topics and describe the topic if exits using ssl in kafka because that command is also not working.

Along with that I have tried every answer on SO but still no success.

The documentation I have followed [Installing ssl on kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_overview)

Comment: Please share how you are trying to connect.

Comment: So I have create a CA and then sign the certificates using the same which I imported inside client.keystore